# I have json-smart 2.4.10 but in dependency tree, it shows 2.3

Tags: java, maven

I'm in a module with

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.minidev</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.10</version>
</dependency>
```

However, when I do `mvn dependency:tree` it's still showing `2.3`:

```
[INFO] +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:compile
```

There's no other spot where I can find json-smart 2.3, I checked the entire multi module project, but nowhere it shows 2.3. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: several things you want to check: 1. where is that dependency defined? In your parent project or in module?  2. where were you running the dependency-tree? in root project or module?  3. Are there other dependecies/dependencyManagement dependency defined for this group + artifactId?    You should be able to create a MRE to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: @AdrianShum I did CMD + SHIFT + F and searched all files and made sure there's no 2.3 anywhere. I ran the dependency tree in the module. There's no dependencyManagement in the current module or the parent module, only in other modules, and they don't have json-smart 2.3. MRE as in you'd like the dependency tree output?

Comment: Try running dependency tree with  [-Dverbose](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html#verbose) parameter to see full output with omitted entries. It should give you an answer on what is going on...

Answer (score 2):

The issue was that there's a transitive dependency that was overwriting the root dependency. Removing the root dependency exposed where the transitive dependency was, then excluding it. This resolved it.